# Old story about space spiders

Tags: story-identification

This is really hard to remember, early 1960s I was sitting in class (UK)  while the teacher read us a tale.
He said it was historical satire.

The basics I recall is a war between the solar system planets and one of them, maybe Venus, was attacking Earth. They used giant spiders to spin webs between the worlds and their men-at-arms marched across.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is Lucien's *[A True Story](https://www.sacred-texts.com/cla/luc/true/tru01.htm)*. It's literally the first science fiction story.

> The infantry came to about sixty million, and was deployed as follows. Spiders in that country are numerous and large, all of them far larger than the Cyclades islands. They were commissioned by the king to span the air between the Moon and the Morning Star with a web, and as soon as they had finished and had made a plain, he deployed his infantry on it.

Satire, yes. Historical, not so much ;-)

Comment: There was also the novel where vegetation had taken over Earth and the moon was stationary -- I think spiders climbed between Luna and Earth on a bridge made of vegetation. Not it probably. Aldiss' Hothouse which is one crazy novel.

Comment: I was like 7 or 8 years old, Mr Bolton said it was historical satire, sir was god in those days

Comment: The _satire_ was historical, not the story. The opening makes it pretty clear that he’s parodying the travelogues of the time, which often included ridiculous and fantastical claims that were far removed from reality but still seemed ‘down to Earth’ by then modern sensibilities. And it does read like those old travelogues, but cranked up to 11 (much like Cervantes's _Don Quixote_ reads much like the romances of chivalry it was intended to poke fun at, cranked up to 11).

Comment: I would say A True Story is definitely a historic work of literature. Not a work *about* history, but a work of some minor historic importance as literature.